# PyQt5 Save QlineEdit to text file with QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a GUI with a save function through the QFileDialog. But it terminates it self everytime, when I try to save.

Here is my code for the function I'm passing through a button.

```
def saveInput(self):   

    name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(MainWindow, "Save File", '/', '.txt')
    file = open(name, 'w')
    text = self.lineEdit.text()
    file.write(text)
    file.close()
```

Here is the whole code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

class Ui_MainWindow(object):


    def saveInput(self):   

        name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(MainWindow, "Save File", '/', '.txt')
        file = open(name, 'w')
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        file.write(text)
        file.close()    


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(431, 275)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


        self.save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 75, 23))
        self.save.setObjectName("save")
        self.save.clicked.connect(self.saveInput)        

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.text()


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 431, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It would help if you would provide the error message.

Comment: There is no error message. The console just says <terminated>file.py[C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QFileDialogs getSaveFileName returns a tuple. You want the first part of that tuple, which is the name entered.

```
name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(MainWindow, "Save File", '/', '.txt')[0]
```

Also note, if you will run scripts from the command line/terminal it will output an error which you can use to diagnose problems like this.

Comment: Additionally, you may use `name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(MainWindow, "Save File", '/', '.txt')`